# Weighted Sampling Based on a data.frame of Probabilities

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame containing 4 columns containing sampling weights.

```
probs <- data.frame(
    group=rep(c(1,2,3), each=4), 
    metric=rep(rep(c("A", "B"), each=2), each=1), 
    measurement=rep(c("HI", "LO"), 6), 
    probability=c(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.05,0.95)
)

probs
   group metric measurement probability
1      1      A          HI        0.80
2      1      A          LO        0.20
3      1      B          HI        0.50
4      1      B          LO        0.50
5      2      A          HI        0.70
6      2      A          LO        0.30
7      2      B          HI        0.40
8      2      B          LO        0.60
9      3      A          HI        0.10
10     3      A          LO        0.90
11     3      B          HI        0.05
12     3      B          LO        0.95
```

which we read as: "In group 1, metric A has a value of HI with probability 0.8 and LO with probability 0.2."

I have another data.frame of observations:

```
data <- data.frame(
    group=sample(c(1,2), size=12, replace=TRUE), 
    metric=sample(c("A", "B"), replace=TRUE, size=12),
    measurement=NA  # To be sampled
)

   group metric measurement
1      2      B          NA
2      2      A          NA
3      2      A          NA
4      1      A          NA
5      2      A          NA
6      1      A          NA
7      1      A          NA
8      2      B          NA
9      2      B          NA
10     2      B          NA
11     1      A          NA
12     1      A          NA
```

How can I efficiently sample a value for `measurement` (values `HI` and `LO`) using the conditional distributions in `probs` for each row in `data`?

Comment: I want to see if anyone else has ideas. If not, I will accept one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way:

Firstly, we define a function that samples by `group` and `metric` given probabililty:

```
sim_meas <- function(x,y){
  bb <- probs %>% 
    group_by(group,metric) %>% 
    mutate(sim_meas = sample(measurement, size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = probability)) %>% 
    filter(group == x & metric == y)   
  return(bb$sim_meas[1])
}
```

Secondly, we simulate measurement using this function:

```
data$measurement <- apply(data,1,function(x) sim_meas(x[1],x[2]))
```

A simulated result:

```
> data
   group metric measurement
1      1      A          HI
2      2      A          HI
3      2      A          HI
4      1      A          HI
5      2      B          LO
6      1      A          HI
7      2      A          HI
8      1      A          HI
9      1      B          HI
10     2      B          HI
11     1      B          LO
12     1      B          LO
```

Comment: This method is 10x faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this:

Expand your initial probability value table by basically making each combination you defined into 10000 rows (so 1 and A for .8 and .2 you'll get 8000 HI and 2000 rows LO in the measurement column)

```
probs <- probs %>%
      mutate(probability = 10000*probability) %>%
      mutate(measurement =as.character(measurement)) %>%
      uncount(probability)
```

Then you can make a function to subset the data to your condition of interest, 
pull the measurements and then randomly sample those 10000 measurements.

```
sample_groups <- function(group, metric, probs){
      probs %>%
            filter(group == group, metric == metric) %>%
            pull(measurement) %>%
            sample(., 1)
}
```

Finally, use mapply to get the metric and group per row to make the measurement variable.

```
data$measurement <- mapply(function(x,y) sample_groups(x, y, probs),
                           data$group, data$metric)
```